# How can I run Openstack devstack in my ASUS chromebook?

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, devstack, chromebook, crouton-os

I use crouton to host a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS os on my chromebook and I am trying to use the devstack of the openstack. However, when I run ./stack.sh, I got error message saying:

```
df: '/mnt/stateful_partition': No such file or directory
df: '/usr/share/oem': No such file or directory
df: '/home/chronos': No such file or directory
df: '/home/.shadow/8ffdc7dfab0156490faeb957f20259a78406cdfa/mount': No such file or directory
df: '/home/chronos/user': No such file or directory
df: '/home/user/8ffdc7dfab0156490faeb957f20259a78406cdfa': No such file or directory
df: '/home/chronos/u-8ffdc7dfab0156490faeb957f20259a78406cdfa': No such file or directory
df: '/home/root/8ffdc7dfab0156490faeb957f20259a78406cdfa': No such file or directory
df: '/run/crw': No such file or directory
+ exit 1
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

- I tried run the script as a root and it doesn't work either

Comment: OpenStack is designed to be run as a non-root user; Horizon will fail to run
# as **root** since Apache will not serve content from **root** user).
# ``stack.sh`` must not be run as **root**. It aborts and suggests one course of
# action to create a suitable user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel this to be as SD card issue. Did you install ubuntu directly on your Chromebook SSD/SD??

The chances of this being openstack issue seems low.

Comment: I don't think I did. I am using crouton to host ubuntu and I don't think it writes that in my SSD/SD. So it would be an issue of crouton right?